# Putting an html response into a php variable

Tags: php, html

I have a php file `myfile.php` which is basically a lot of html and some php code within, for example:

```
<body> 
    Name: <?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>
    <!-- and so on ... -->  
</body>
```

I am using an open-source HTML to PDF converter written in PHP which requires as an input the html content to be converted:

```
PDFConverter::convertHTMLToPDFFIle($html_input, $filename_output_pdf);
```

How can I feed in the html generated from `myfile.php?id=XX` into `$html_input`?

Comment: Slight difference - query string in php file

Comment: It's the same, you are using PHP between two files, it's a requirement of the language to intercommunicate with his own files, in this case, passing a var.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a little output buffering and include it.

```
<?php
ob_start();
include "myfile.php";
$content = ob_get_clean();
// $content now contains the processed code of myfile
```

At that point, the file contents has been processed by PHP because of the include and is in the `$content` variable. You can pass that to your `convertHTMLToPDFFile()` method.

```
PDFConverter::convertHTMLToPDFFile($content, $outFilename);
```

EDIT: OP edited question adding requirement that the included file needs to be able to accept variables.

When a file is included/required, it inherits the current scope. That means it has access to any variables, class definitions, functions, etc. that are defined. So, determine which variables are shared and set those values before including the file. For example:

```
<body> 
Name: <?php echo $id; ?>
<!-- and so on ... ->  
</body>
```

and then...

```
<?php
ob_start();
$id = <whatever the value should be>;
include "myfile.php";
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Can I pass GET variables with `include "myfile.php?id=xx"` ?

Comment: not like that - that'd be just a file inclusion, and any $_GET variables in the myfile.php would be processed with the values already in scope. If you ABSOLUTELY MUST pass values like that, you could include it as a full-URL assuming your PHP hasn't disabled remote includes as a security risk, but there are better/safer/saner ways to do something like that so you really shouldn't be in that situation. If you are, reconsider your approach.

Comment: I just need to pass the php file an `id`, it doesnt matter whether it goes through the query string or any other means. What would be another way of passing the `id` to the php file?

Comment: Why not just `$content = file_get_contents("myfile.php")`??!!

Comment: when it's included it will inherit the current scope, so you can take advantage of that by setting shared variables. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @ColeJohnson because that loads it in as text and no processing.

Answer (score 2):

If you have fopen url wrappers enabled on your host you can use file get contents

```
 $html = file_get_contents("http://mysite.com/somefile.php?var=1&var2=2");
```